# Why does Yokodera idolize Oscar Wilde?

Tags: hentai-ouji-to-warawanai-neko

At many points in the story, Yokodera references Oscar Wilde with a sense of admiration and quotes him fairly frequently. This is done for a variety of reasons, from justifying his own actions to advising others, but in all cases it seems that Yokodera takes Wilde as a sort of role model.

[image]

Is it ever explained why he is so influenced by Wilde, to the exclusion of pretty much anyone else?

Comment: I didn't really notice the recurrence, can you quote more instances of this?

Comment: @nhahtdh I only know of this one instance from the manga (from chapter 12, which is the most recent chapter I've read), but there are several in the light novels. I'll go look and see if I can find others, but it's been a while since I've read them so I don't really remember where, only that he was referenced several times.

Comment: It's true Oscar Wilde is referenced quite a few times in this manga. I don't want to spoil anything, but more references to Oscar Wilde will come later than chapter 12 too. I don't think you will find an explanation in the manga itself. However Oscar Wilde was known for being considered as a pervert (but mostly because he was homosexual in times when homosexuality was considered perversion). Maybe the scenarist is somehow a fan of Oscar Wilde?

Comment: I don't know if you can cite fansubs (as I don't understand japanese THAT much) but from some subs, they said that Yokodera idolizes Oscar Wilde simply because he thinks he's a pervert - somehow implying that even for someone as intellectual as Wilde can be a pervert (and that there's nothing wrong with it)

Answer (score 1):

The manga never explains why exactly he is so fond of Mr. Wilde. It is possible that he views him as a pervy role model and inspiration, being notorious for his (homo)sexual shenanigans. Yet I don't think this is the main reason, since this is a het ecchi series, which tend to view homosexuality as squick.

It is more likely a reference to the nature of Wilde's works, which Yokodera has almost certainly read, given how often he quotes from them. They tend to focus on similar issues to the ones he's facing: e.g., [The Importance of Being Earnest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Importance_of_Being_Earnest) deals with matters of saving face, when to lie and not, the purpose and functions of social graces and hierarchy, and of course, How To Get The Girl! Not to mention the tone is almost always light, irreverent and satirical of his "social betters". All of this mirrors issues within his own life, and so he likely feels Wilde is a kindred spirit. (And not least, he's a very entertaining author to read, and eminently quotable for every occasion!)